# stringWithFormat produces string with gibberish characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsstring

When debugging the following code

```
NSString *var1 = @"blaa";
NSString *var2 = @"blaaaaa";

NSString* script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Set_Variable( %s, %s )",var1,var2];
```

the `%s` placeholders in script are replaced with funny gibberish characters.
Can you see any errors in the code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

%s is the format specifier for a C string, char*

For objective-c objects (such as NSString) you should use %@